# UICollectionview slow data reloading

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uicollectionview

I make a request, get data, split them into 10 arrays and it takes like 2 seconds. But sorting them into `UICollectionView` takes almost 10 seconds to show data. Here is my code:

```
func makeRequest() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.example.com/v1/ticker/?start=" + "\(startingPoint)")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let urlContent = data {
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [AnyObject]
                    var i: Int!
                    for i in 0..<jsonResult.count {
                        Global.rankArray.append(String(describing: jsonResult[i]["rank"]!!))
                        // 9 other similar lines 
                    }
                    // Loading some views
                    self.dataCollection.reloadData()
                } catch {
                    print("Error")
              }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

So I can print everything quickly but no data is showing in the `UICollectionView` until 10 seconds pass. The loading time doesn't rely on the internet connection speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are reloading your UICollectionView on a background thread.  Anything that should immediately update the view must be run on the main thread.  Simply change your reload statement:

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.dataCollection.reloadData()
   }
```